# Allow only numbers in Input field IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok Well. I want to restrict input field to accept only numbers with maxlength 5 characters.

**My Try:**

HTML

```
 <input type="number" maxlength="5" onKeyDown="numbersOnly(event);/>
 <input type="text" pattern= "[0-9]" onKeyDown="numbersOnly(event);/>
```

Javascript

```
   function numbersOnly(event,length) 
   {  
    return event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
    || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
    || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
    || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
    || (event.keyCode==46)
    || (event.keyCode>47)&&(event.keyCode<=57) ;
   }
```

All works in firefox. But when i check with safari ipad, it accepts special characters like ()@!#$&. I used alert function for debugging. It returns same keyCode for @ and 2 , 3 and # and so on. I tried keyUp,keyPress events and event.charCode,event.which,event.key. Nothing works

So how to differentiate it and i need support for backspace , enter , delete, arrow keys also.

Comment: `numbersOnly` is javascript function and not jquery, and can you tell us where you are calling this function?

Comment: See the answers to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390665/html-input-that-takes-only-numbers-and-the-symbol/37421357 - you could write e. g. `<input type="text" data-filter="[0-9]{0,5}">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made this once and haven't been able to break it. Tested on iPad.

```
// Prevent NULL input and replace text.
$(document).on('change', 'input[type="number"]', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');
    if (this.value < 1) this.value = 0;
});

// Block non-numeric chars.
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type="number"]', function (event) {
    return (((event.which > 47) && (event.which < 58)) || (event.which == 13));
});
```

This also accounts for copy/paste and drag and drop text, which people often forget. You can add the max-length to the onchange.

Comment: Yes, backspace and such don't fire `keypress` events. You can always add keys there if you need certain special chars though.

Comment: And that doesn't get removed in the onchange? `this.value.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '');` Can you explain how you break it, since I haven't been able to.

Comment: `return event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
        || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
        || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
        || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
        || (event.keyCode==46)
        || (event.which >47)&&(event.which <=57) ;` This is what i added in my function

Comment: The above code i pasted is the modification of yours. I added `which` to only numbers

Comment: Minor bug: pasting text containing +,- or e causes your input to be cleared to 0. Also, an empty input accepts pasting +,- or e into it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `type="number"` on an input prevents you from reading non-numerical input values via `input.value` (it will then return an empty string) and thus eliminates the possibility of filtering invalid user input (+-.e) while keeping the valid numbers. Thus you have to use `type="text"`. Example:

```js
$('.input-number').on('input', function (event) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="input-number" type="text" maxlength="5">
```

If you want the text-cursor not to move when pasting or typing invalid input, have a look at my answer to a similar question here: [HTML input that takes only numbers and the + symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390665/html-input-that-takes-only-numbers-and-the-symbol/37421357#37421357)

Comment: hey @le_m, thanks for the answer :), couple of quick Q's, 1) I didn't understand the `type="number"` explanation - could you please elaborate a bit, 2) I could not see this behavior "If you want the text-cursor not to move when pasting or typing invalid input", could you please tell how to reproduce the issue - so can check the other solution - but as this is working super fine I'm thinking why not use your answer :) --- Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Be careful the iOS keyCodes are not the same desktop computers. See [IOS keyCodes in Javascript](http://notes.ericjiang.com/posts/333)

```
<input type="number" maxlength="5" onkeypress="numbersOnly(event);/>

 var numbersOnly = function(event) {
        if(event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
            return false;
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enter the only numbers in input type number fields. this will be helpful, It will work on iPhone and iPad as well.

```
 $(document).on('keypress', 'input[type="number"]', function (event) {
    return event.code.includes('Digit') || event.code.includes('Numpad') ||  event.code.includes('Period');;
});
```